# Why is MVC4 project Membership DB Table 'Membership' & not 'aspnet_Membership'?

Tags: t-sql, asp.net-mvc-4

If you create a new MVC4 web application with the Internet Application Project Template in VS2010, the aspnet DB has six tables :

Applications,
Memberships,
Profiles,
Roles,
Users
& UsersInRoles

If I use the aspnet_regsql.exe tool The tables names are aspnet_Membership etc.. but all have 'aspnet_' MVC4 tables dont have this schema! They have the above names (no 'aspnet_' in sight)

I have even copied the scripts aspnet_regsql.exe uses directly from :

C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319 to use in Sql Server Management Studio

and the results are the same... 'aspnet_' is used.

The MVC4 table columns are slightly different too (there's no MobilePIN column in the Membership table), so is there another provider at work here?

Why does MVC4 produce these slightly different tables?

Comment: Ok, providers are not the same, MVC4 introduces new providers -  http://nuget.org/packages/System.Web.Providers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The providers are not the same, MVC4 introduces new providers - nuget.org/packages/System.Web.Providers